# Just adding a UIWebView object to a scene causes a crash

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I'm using the following to open another scene. This is most strange as if I just add a web view to the opened scene storyboard (just dragging it onto the scene), it causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. This is even before I've hooked it up (just adding it to the scene crashes everything). When I remove the web view, it works again. VIEWER is a separate scene on the Main.storyboard. I'm really struggling with this as it is making no sense. I've tried everything I can think of and been sat here for 6 hours (got work in 4 hours!) Please help me if you know why just adding a web view to a scene would cause a crash.

```
            UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *viewVC = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VIEWER"];
            viewVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentViewController:viewVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: having the same problem, waiting for answers; also tried use WKWebView instead, not crashing, but not displaying anything either